# How to never stack photos and always show all photos in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

These are really 2 separate items but I dislike both features equally:
Is there a setting that would disable the stacking feature?  Is there a way to completely disable this feature?
I would like to always see all photos in my catalog even after a new batch of photos was imported.

Comment: You seem to imply that you have unwanted stacks? What causes them to appear in your Library. I always see all my images because they are not stacked and they are not stacked because I didn't stack them. So are you using a function or plugin which creates stacks for you?

Comment: NIK Plugins mostly. But it also stacks images processed in CS5 when get back in LR. Sometimes they are not stacked but after closing and opening LR they have been stacked with like photos.  I also have the option to stack when processing bracketed exposures in Photomatix but I unstack the image upon arrival in LR because otherwise they are not placed in the right sequence.

Comment: That is good to know. That's a lot of software trying to organize your images for you :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if stacking can be completely disabled, however why are the photos stacked in the first place? You will be asked if you want to stack when exporting for an external editor and 'stacking' of JPEG and RAW files can be disabled in the preferences. What more ways are there, that photos could get stacked, where you do not actively do it?

Concerning the second point: If you have one folder that contains all photos (also in sub-directories) you can simply select this folder, or even the entire drive, to see all indexed photos that are on it. If there are several folders/drives you can select multiple ones, using CTRL. A more elegant solution might be the creation of a Smart collection with a filter, that simply applies to all photos, e.g. Star rating between 0 and 5.

*Edit: I cannot verify right now, but apparently stacking does not apply when within a collection (see [here](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1006&message=38867025&changemode=1)). Therefore using one big collection might actually solve both problems

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to always see all photos in my catalog even after a new batch of photos was imported.

In the left sidebar look at the "Catalog" section. Normally you would use the "All Photographs" selection. After importing the "Previous Import" item is selected. Just pick "All Photographs" again.